# How to flat and merge a list of dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I convert a list of dictionaries into a single dictionary? Given:

```
data = [
    {
        "name" : "name1",
        "type" : "type1",
    },
    {
        "name" : "name2",
        "type" : "type2",
    }
]
```

I want to turn the above into a single dictionary:

```
data = {
    "name" : "name1 | name2",
    "type" : "type1 | type2"
}
```

Obs: I getting that list from an API request, so it can be more than 2 dictionaries in a list.

I know how to do it using Pandas, in this case I want to measure which one is faster.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:

One option is to iterate over the dictionaries and append the values as list items. Then you do a final join on that list to make it a | seperated string. For example

```
data = [
    {
        "name" : "name1",
        "type" : "type1",
    },
    {
        "name" : "name2",
        "type" : "type2",
    }
]


new_data = {'name': [],
            'type': []
           }

for my_dict in data:

    new_data['name'].append(my_dict['name'])
    new_data['type'].append(my_dict['type'])

new_data['name'] = " | ".join(new_data['name'])
new_data['type'] = " | ".join(new_data['type'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```py
data = [
    {
        "name": "name1",
        "type": "type1",
    },
    {
        "name": "name2",
        "type": "type2",
    },
]

out = {}
for d in data:
    for k, v in d.items():
        out.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
out = {k: " | ".join(v) for k, v in out.items()}
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{'name': 'name1 | name2', 'type': 'type1 | type2'}
```

---

OR:  If your dictionaries contains only `name`/`type` keys:

```py
out = {n: " | ".join(d[n] for d in data) for n in ("name", "type")}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one line like this:

```py
data = [
    {
        "name" : "name1",
        "type" : "type1",
    },
    {
        "name" : "name2",
        "type" : "type2",
    }
]

data2 = {k: " | ".join(d[k] for d in data) for k in data[0]}

print(data2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [
{
    "name" : "name1",
    "type" : "type1",
},
{
    "name" : "name2",
    "type" : "type2",
}
]

# Iterate through keys in both dictionaries
result = {}
for key in set([d.keys() for d in data]):
    # create a list with the values ignoring Nones
    result[key] = [d.get(key, None) for d in data if d.get(key, None)]

# convert the list to strings name1 | name2
for key,value in result.items():
    d[k] = " | ".join([str(x) for x in d[k]])
```